# Get data from DocumentReference flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, triggers

I am trying to update a document using a Cloud Store trigger function. Below is the code but when I try to deploy the function I get this error:
**119:30  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token deviceDoc
✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)**

```
exports.onTrxnUpdate = functions.firestore.document('/trxns/{trxnId}').onUpdate((change, context) => {
    
    const afterData = change.after.data();
    const agentId = afterData.agentId;
    console.log('agentId: ', afterData.agentId);
    console.log('A transaction has been updated');
    
    /**** GET DEVICE INFORMATION ****/
    const deviceDoc = db.collection('device').doc(agentId);
    console.log('deviceDoc: ', deviceDoc);
    if (deviceDoc == null) {
        console.log('No device document found');
    } 
    
    const deviceData = await deviceDoc.get(); <<<< THIS IS THE PROBLEM CODE

});
```

The last line is the one that is causing the error but I don't know why. I use this same line in another function and it works there.

Please help!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `async` to your callback like below:

```js
   exports.onTrxnUpdate = functions.firestore.document('/trxns/{trxnId}').onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    //... rest of the code
    });
```